# Remove Hyperledger Fabric Network with Kafka orderer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hyperledger-fabric

In order to bring down a hyperledger fabric network with Kafka-Zookeeper orderers, what components [docker images/containers etc ] will need to be removed in order, so that the system has no residual data of previous network?

Comment: How did you create / bring up the network initially?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.I have used docker to create an overlay network and launched the network using containers with " docker run " command

Comment: In general, you just need to destroy the orderer, Kafka and Zookeeper containers.   If you also mounted external volumes, you will need to delete the data in those volumes as well.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you very much for your inputs.